# Unable to open any of Stackoverflow questions

Tags: support, error-message

For over a month or so I have not been able to open any of the StackOverflow question links. Clicking on any of the link end up in run time error as mentioned below. I have tried with different browsers and all end up in the same error. It appears to be problem when I open the links from my system. I have been able to open links from other machines.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.
```

Comment: If you can't open any question, how exactly do you post answers, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15052879/447356)? Anyway, can you monitor the network via the browser tools and see maybe there are some details there?

Comment: This is likely to be a DNS issue.

Comment: I can open in another machine but not on the machine I regularly use.

Comment: Thanks @Pekka. Your link helped. My hosts file was pointing Stackoverflow to 69.59.197.21. Removing this solved problem. Thanks a lot.